# floating point precision using memcpy C++

Tags: c++, floating-point, memcpy, floating-point-precision, floating-point-conversion

I have a tricky problem that I do not understand. I have an array of uint8_t that I need to convert to a 32 bit floating point. I am using memcpy to accomplish that...however the rounding seems to be off. Could someone please explain what is happening/a solution to this issue, thanks in advance. The coefficientByteSwap array contains two coefficients, one in the first four bytes, and other in the 2nd four bytes.

```
static float32_t coefficient[ALLSENSORS][NUM_QUADRATIC_FIELDS];
uint8_t coefficientByteSwap[8];


memcpy(&coefficient[sensor][2], &coefficientByteSwap[0], sizeof(float32_t));
memcpy(&coefficient[sensor][3], &coefficientByteSwap[4], sizeof(float32_t));
```

example:

```
coefficientByteSwap[0] = 0xE8
coefficientByteSwap[1] = 0x32
coefficientByteSwap[2] = 0xB5
coefficientByteSwap[3] = 0xBC
```

should be a floating point value of: -.022119
but when I print it out it comes out: -.022119000554

Comment: Indirect casting from `float` representation assumptions is probably a bad idea!

Comment: you can't represent that number as a floating point. If you want more precision, you can use a `double` instead, but there is no way to get infinite precision with a finite size variable.

Comment: `BCB532E8` is actually `-0.022119000554`, not `-0.22119`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumption is wrong.
Look at this:

```
float f = -.022119;
std::cout << std::setprecision(20) << f << std::endl;
```

Prints:
-0.022119000554084778

Comment: @user2494298: It's like the error you get representing 2/3 in decimal. It repeats infinitely, so you have to cut it off somewhere.